# Choosing random WebElement from drop down using Selenium with Java

Tags: java, selenium

I'm automating our application using Selenium 2.0 and Java. I would like to get a clearer understanding how can I overcome the problem with generating random ID for my WebElement and then click on it.
I have a list of elements in my drop down that all differs only in endings:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(""uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_1")
driver.findElement(By.id(""uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_2")
driver.findElement(By.id(""uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_3")
driver.findElement(By.id(""uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_4")
```

and so on till 250.

What I did is I called Random class where I declared a random variable within the range 1 to 250

```
Random random = new Random();
    int x = random.nextInt(250) + 1;
```

Now I'm searching for my element this way

```
private WebElement cruiseSailing = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));
```

That's all OK and is working as expected. The problem I'm facing is sometimes error message appears after selecting some of those elements from drop down. According to my test case, I need to catch this error, capture the screenshot and choose another element from the drop down. But once I set up `cruiseSailing` element, it chooses the same element over and over.Please see code example below:

```
    private WebElement cruiseSailingDropDown = driver.findElement(By.id(Some ID));
    private WebElement errorMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("some xpath expression"));
    private WebElement cruiseSailing = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));


    cruiseSailingDropDown.click();
    cruiseSailing.click();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    if(errorMessage .isDisplayed){
    System.out.printLn("Error message is displayed")
    cruiseSailingDropDown.click();
    cruiseSailing.click();
    }else{
    proceed further to the next step
```

Please advise how can I generate another ID for my cruiseSailing webelement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it is choosing the same element again in case of failure is you are not reassigning the cruiseSailing value to new one .

There are 2 ways which i can think of :

1. Assign a new value to cruiseSailing  inside the "If" block. You can do something as below inside "If" block.

   cruiseSailing = driver.findElement(By.id("uxMiniFinderVoyageSelect_chzn_o_" + x));
2. Call the Orignial method again  which sets cruiseSailing value to new value.

**Note:** You might want to remove below lines from If block if you are going on with 2nd approach.

```
cruiseSailingDropDown.click();
cruiseSailing.click();
```

For Taking screenshot you can create a method and call it inside If block.

Code for taking screenshot

```
File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);

 // Now you can do whatever you need to do with it, for example copy somewhere
FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("c:\\error\\screenshot.png"));
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I had a question. So, for second approach you recommend to call original method and not to use cruiseSailingDropDown.click() and cruiseSailing.click() in if block. But if I remove them from this block, my code will just console the error message and will proceed further without trying to call a new value for cruiseSailing element. Can you specify how exactly I should use second approach because the first approach you've offered brings more code to my class.

Comment: So when you call original method which means in this case the block of code which you have provided  it will have assign new value to cruiseSailing and click the same from dropdown . I'm assuming the block which you have provide is a method so calling same block in case of failure should help.

Comment: No this is not a separate method, it's just an actions within the class. But anyway, you helped me in any way. Thanks.